# the eye is on the opposite side and i cant make to the other side using mirror

Tags: modifiers, mirror

[image]so im trying to make the eyes to the other side of the face but everytime i do mirror it goes to the opposite side
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo4gx.jpg

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome! You can upload your image here, and it will be easier to get help that way.

Did you select the head as the target for the mirror modifier?
If you did, maybe you need to set the origin to geometry. To do this, select the head, right-click, and choose "Set Origin", then select "Origin to Geometry"

Comment: i  added a photo so u can check thanks for replying

Comment: Hello maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

By default the Mirror Modifier use the position and rotation of the modifier object. So, you need to change the target of the mirror modifier. In your case the head.

You can click there and select the mesh that you want to use as a mirror, or use the Eyedropper and click on the head.

[image]